# Possible fraudulent mail received regarding employee benefits

Tags: human-resources, benefits

I am a relatively new employee and I'm only several weeks into my new job. Today I received a letter in the mail regarding my employee benefits account being successfully set up, the particular type for which I don't remember having elected to sign up for. The company administering the benefits plan from which the letter came from was different from the company stated in the information from HR I received on my first day.

Having worked in compliance and audit roles in the past, I felt this mismatch along with other tell-tale hints in the mailing constitute red flags of fraud. I received this email far sooner than I should have according to HR paperwork. My employer was not mentioned anywhere in the mailing. The envelope did not look professional and language on it is consistent with fraud tactics (urgent language to action...etc).

**How can I approach my employer / HR to validate this event?**

Update: HR confirmed this letter was indeed fraudulent. They are investigating and I also filed a complaint with USPS, given the mail was used for delivery.

Comment: Take the email and envelope to HR and ask, "is this from you?"

Comment: I'm a tad bit surprised you mention working for Compliance and Audit roles, and your first instinct isn't to ask the people normally responsible for the correspondence. If there's one thing that should be hammered home it's `verify suspicious correspondence with a person directly responsible`.

Comment: Be careful (not with approaching HR). This might have been stab in the dark from the scammer, but the timing suggests that the scammer has more information about you. If your company's name (or more that generally public information) is on the letter anywhere, your private/confidential information may have been leaked or sold (possibly by you, did you update Linked In?)

Comment: If this is a scam, I would guess that you updated your LinkedIn or other social network site to say you have a new job. The scammer has a bot that picked up this information and sent you your "new employee benefits".

Answer (score 70, accepted):

> How can I approach my employer / HR to validate this event?

Simply bring the letter to HR, explain your concerns and listen to what they say.

It's their job to either tell you to disregard the fraudulent mail (and then track down how it happened and deal with it), or to explain how this is non-fraudulent mail and clear up your confusion.

No big deal here - just let HR handle it.

Comment: Even if it is legitimate, the presentation still is deceptive (makes it falsely appear fake / from an unrelated source) and should be corrected.

Comment: And avoid saying anything that could be considered an accusation, just a simple "I just want to check if this mail is OK" would be enough.

Comment: I wouldn't even worry about the accusation - there's details you don't recall agreeing to, so either (a) it's fake and HR needs to know - you may not be the only one to get one of these - or (b) it's legit but incorrect and HR needs to know. Either way, as long as you don't go thundering into the room throwing verbal grenades in all directions, HR should be happy to see you.